# Publishing ASP.NET vs. copying files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know for sure if there are any possible issues for not publishing an ASP.NET solution.

In my company current policy (strangely) they just copy the web project dll, and needed references dlls, web.config and global.ASAX and image files over the existing ones on the IIS web server(Virtual Directory is created).

Do you see any issue with the above?

Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't think this is really a question for stackoverflow, but I can't see any issues other than the factor of human error: you're bound to forget some changed/added files

Comment: that's all publishing does when you publish to the file system

Comment: I don't know if this is an appropriate SO question because it's kind of a poll/discussion question. However, doing this is a recipe for disaster. I contracted one place where this was the policy and it was one DLL version conflict or config error after another when deploying.

Comment: If the dll version conflict, then publishing the App wont solve the issue either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't really see a problem with this. It's sort of what we do. We publish to a folder - any folder, check the web.config against live, then zip it up. We then create a change request, referencing the zip file & pass this to the hosting team to deploy.

This works great for us, but then everyone has different views & circumstances. I don't really see it as a technical issue, but more of business process issue.

Comment: We have a similar setup except we promote code through environments. Our web.config file reference config files one root up above the web application which allows us to have separate configs per environment. If we need changes to those we document those as part of the release and those changes get applied in each environment (DEV, STAGE and PROD). We publish the project locally, migrate to DEV.

Answer (score 1):

It used to be that you copying files was not good enough, because you needed to create a virtual directory/Application within the IIS configuration system for your applications. Recent versions of IIS allow you to handle this entirely within the app.config, and so it's much less of an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about this situation that web app is already deployed. That is virtual directory/Application is already created. Do still see any possible issues for copying files?